# How to access ViewModel from StateHolder class as mentioned in official Google docs

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

In the official Google docs on compose state management it mentions:

*"Since ViewModels have a longer lifespan than state holders, state holders can take ViewModels as a dependency if needed."*
[Android Developers - ViewModel and state holders](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#viewmodel-state)

It does not provide any example of how to do this.

When i try to use the passed `viewModel()` from `rememberExampleState` in my `ExampleState` i am not able to access it within the `addFromViewModel()` function. I get error `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`.

How can I access my viewModel in the state holder class?

```
class ExampleState(
    viewModel: MainActivityViewModel
) {
    //Screen or UI state
    var viewModelList = viewModel.someViewModelList //access to viewModel works fine here
    fun addFromViewModel() {
        viewModelList = viewModel.someViewModelFunction //??? error here when accessing viewModel within function
    }
}

@Composable
fun rememberExampleState(
    viewModel: MainActivityViewModel = viewModel()
) : ExampleState {
    return remember {
        ExampleState(
            viewModel = viewModel
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun ExampleScreen(state: ExampleState = rememberExampleState()) {
    for (item in state.viewModelList) {
        Column {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, you can't inject it with hilt. Your code already seems to provide the needed view model: `rememberExampleState` getting it with `viewModel()` and pass to `ExampleState` init, so I can't get what's the problem?

Comment: @PylypDukhov Thanks i will rule out the hilt approach then. The issue with using the passed `viewModel` in `ExampleState` parameter is that it is a composable invocation, so i cannot use it inside `addFromViewModel()` otherwise i get error: `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`. Do you know how to correctly implement the `addFromViewModel` function added to OP?

Comment: It is declared as constructor parameter, add `private val` before `viewModel` name to store it.

Comment: @PylypDukhov thanks this seems to work now. I am not sure why it fixed, do you know any useful articles to understand why that helped? Sorry one final question, would the passed `viewModel()` be using the same instance as my dagger/hilt singleton?

Comment: By adding `val` you're creating a class property initialized with constructor parameter of the same name. Without `val` constructor parameter can only be used to initialize other class parameters, but not after initialization. This is feature of Kotlin language, you can check out [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html).

Comment: Basically view model scope is bind to your activity, so `viewModel()` is gonna return the same object every time. But if you're using Compose Navigation, each route will have it's own view model scope.

Comment: @PylypDukhov i have asked another question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71811094/add-elements-to-mutablestatelist-in-state-holder-class-using-remembersaveable that is follow up on this one. It is also references a separate user question which you have asked, hence thought you may be able to help.